# flask UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shift1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask

*********************I am trying to make notice board using flask , code was working perfectly before but suddenly stopped working. Please help.I don't have much experience with flask , I've also tried to declare the variable global

---

Python(flask) code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime
import MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'




@app.route('/')  
def index():

  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().time()

  if datetime.time(7, 30) <= timestamp <= datetime.time(15, 29):
    shift1 = "A"
  elif datetime.time(15, 30) <= timestamp <= datetime.time(23, 29):
    shift1 = "B"
  elif datetime.time(23, 30) <= timestamp <= datetime.time(7, 29):
    shift1 = "C"
  return render_template('hello.html', month=now.month, date=now.day, year=now.year, hour=now.hour, minute=now.minute, second=now.second, shift=shift1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
setInterval(function() {
                  window.location.reload();
                }, 1000); 

</script>

<style>
table, td, tr {
    text-align: center;
    height: 72px;
    font-size: 53;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" width="100%" height="941px">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><p align="centre"><font color="blue">{{ date }} / {{ month }} / {{ year }}</font></p></td>
<td colspan="4"><p align="centre"><font color="blue">{{ hour }} : {{ minute }} : {{ second }}</font></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"></td>
<td colspan="2" ><font>Shift:</td>
<td colspan="1" ><font color="red">{{ shift }}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"  width="20%"><font size="28" color="green">Plan</td>
<td width="10%">1</td>
<td></td>
<td rowspan="8" colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
<td width="10%">2</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%">3</td>
<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td width="10%">4</td>
<td></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"height="50px" width="20%"><font size="28" color="green">Actual</td>
<td width="10%">5</td>
<td></td>

</tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="3"></td>
<td width="10%">6</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="10%">7</td>
<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td width="10%">8</td>
<td></td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yjZm.png)

Comment: Please include all errors in the question as code blocks

Answer (score 2):

Your time comparisons are flawed; you are ignoring the seconds component of a `time()` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.time(15, 29, 30) <= datetime.time(15, 29)
False
>>> datetime.time(15, 29, 30) >= datetime.time(15, 30)
False
```

The seconds component defaults to `0`, so `15:29:30` is *later* than `15:29:00`. This means there are timestamps that won't result in any of the `if`..`elif` branches to match, and `shift1` is never set.

Use `<` tests instead, and use better upper boundaries:

```
if datetime.time(7, 30) < timestamp < datetime.time(15, 30):
    shift1 = "A"
elif datetime.time(15, 30) < timestamp < datetime.time(23, 30):
    shift1 = "B"
elif datetime.time(23, 30) < timestamp < datetime.time(7, 30):
    shift1 = "C"
```

For a larger number of shifts, I'd use bisection; set the starting times in a sequence, then use the resulting insertion point for the current time as an index into a sequence of shifts:

```
from bisect import bisect

shift_starts = (datetime.time(7, 30), datetime.time(15, 30), datetime.time(23, 30))
shift_names = 'CABC'  # C twice to account for the time before 7:30
shift_index = bisect(shift_starts, timestamp)
shift1 = shift_names[shift_index]
```